# Modal iFrame for YouTube Not Scaling

Tags: iframe, responsive-design, youtube, bootstrap-modal

This should be simple.  I want to increase the desktop size of my YouTube in a Bootstrap 3 modal, while retaining its responsiveness on smaller devices.  To get the responsiveness, I'm using a wrapper.  That works reasonable well.  But I can't get the iFrame to scale up on desktop.  Here's the code I'm using for the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="trailer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body modalTrailer">
            <iframe width="550" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lgrVfuni7Bg" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen ></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <!--  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The relevant CSS is:

```
div.trailer {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: center; 
}

.modalTrailer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.modalTrailer iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The site is: http://www.antboythemovie.com/index2.html.

And not to violate any rules about multiple questions, but if there is a way to do the responsiveness and resizing simply with bootstrap cols (e.g., col-xs-12) that would be a preferred solution to the wrapper.

Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

you need add class "modal-lg" in `<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="trailer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body modalTrailer">
            <iframe width="550" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lgrVfuni7Bg" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen ></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <!--  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked nicely.  Hope it plays well with smaller devices.